# VisualSVN - Upload Solution with multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I am trying to upload a solution with multiple projects but only the first project gets uploaded. When I try to load any of the others I get error *"Project cannot be added to Subversion because it is out of working copy"*

The folder structure on the drive is:

```
c:\myprojects\thisproject\project1
c:\myprojects\thisproject\project2
c:\myprojects\thisproject\project3
```

How do I remove a solution from the SVN library via VisualSVN? I don't see a remove solution, just add a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to remove a solution from SVN via VisualSvn. The options are either delete or export and only delete can be done, but that also removes the file from the solution and in most cases from the harddrive. VisualSvn offers minimal SVN features: update, commit, delete and branch commands.

I recommend if you are having problems with svn that you used Export from TortoiseSVN. Export removes all the .SVN folders from your solution and copies them to a new location.

If project1 is the root of your subversion repository,  project2 or project3 will not add to your subversion repository.

Comment: yeah - use TortoiseSvn when VisualSvn fails you